# Compact Approximation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

*This thread originated from MSE: [Compact Approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1140841/79762)*

*This is meant as lemma for: [Approximation Property](https://mathoverflow.net/q/196100/45494)*

Given a Banach space $E$.

Denote compact domains by $\mathcal{C}$.

Denote compact operators by $\mathcal{C}(E)$.

Then there is a compact approximate identity:
$$\forall C\in\mathcal{C}\,\exists C_N\in\mathcal{C}(E,E):\quad\|C_N-1\|_C:=\sup_{x\in C}\|C_Nx-x\|\stackrel{N\to\infty}\to0$$

How to construct such compact operators?

Comment: To clarify: your display is asserting that *there exist* compact operators $C_N$ such that this holds?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes exactly. Wait let me add this.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I added it to the question.

Comment: There is not always a compact approximate identity. If there is, we say that $E$ has the compact approximation property.  Enflo actually showed that not every Banach space has the compact approximation approximation property.  Davie's examples are given in volume one of the book of Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri. However, they only prove the failure of the approximation property. You have to go back to Davie's paper to read a proof of the failure of the compact approximation property.

Comment: A.M. Davie, The Banach approximation problem, J. Approx. Theory 13, 392-394, 1975.

Comment: @Freeze_S : or maybe you are talking of nonlinear compact operators?

Comment: @PietroMajer: No I meant linear operators.