# Approximation Property: Characterization

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

**Problem**

Given a Banach space $E$. Denote compact sets by $\mathcal{C}$, compact operators by $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$, and finite rank operators by $\mathcal{F}(X,Y)$.

Suppose it has the approximation property:
$$\forall C\in\mathcal{C}\,\exists T_N\in\mathcal{F}(E):\quad\|T_N-1\|_C:=\sup_{x\in C}\|T_Nx-x\|\stackrel{N\to\infty}{\to}0$$

Then every compact operator is of almost finite rank:
$$\overline{\mathcal{F}(X,E)}=\mathcal{C}(X,E)\subseteq\mathcal{B}(X,E)$$

How do I prove this actual equivalence?

**Attempt**

As the image of the unit ball is precompact one has:
$$C\in\mathcal{C}(X,E):\quad\|T_NC-C\|=\|T_N-1\|_{C(B)}\to0\quad(T_NC\in\mathcal{F}(X,E))$$
For the converse one might try to smuggle in a compact operator:
$$C\subseteq rB:\quad\|T_N-1\|_C\leq r\|T_N-C\|_B+\|C-1\|_C<r\delta_T+\delta_C\quad(C\in\mathcal{C}(E))$$
But how to construct one that approximates the identity?

**Reference**

This thread originated from MSE: [Approximation Property: Characterization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1122760/79762)

As reference the german wiki: [Approximationseigenschaft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximationseigenschaft)

Comment: Can you define some of the notation here?  What are $X$, $E$, $\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{F}(E)$, $\mathcal{C}(X,E)$?  Also, it would help if you make the quantifiers explicit (is your first display asserting the existence of such a sequence $T_n$, or saying it holds for all $T_n \in \mathcal{F}(E)$, or what?)

Comment: @NateEldredge: Sure. One moment please.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: The converse is a non trivial result of Grothendieck's. It is in his AMS Memoirs.

Comment: @BillJohnson: Great thanks!! *(Do you have a link?)*

Comment: No link, but the proof is given in volume one of Lindenstrausr-Tzafriri; Theorem 1.e.4.

Comment: @BillJohnson: Great great great!!! =D

Comment: @BillJohnson: Can you do me one last favor: Post just a very short answer on MSE so I can check it off there. (MSE: [Approximation Property](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1122760/79762), [Compact Approximation](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1140841/79762))

Comment: No need since you did this.  You should reference all cross posts with MSE. Not doing that is considered on MO a discourtesy.

Comment: @BillJohnson: Do you want to give an answer there? *(I would of course withdraw mine!)*

Comment: @BillJohnson: Thanks for warning me. Done! :)